# How to get font size specified in inline style

Tags: jquery, html, css, font-size

Code below prints invalid font size: 16pt in Chrome.
How to fix this so that same font size, 12pt as specified in inline style is returned ?

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            var css = $('#_QNU0OVBMB').css(["font-size"]);
            alert(css["font-size"]);
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="_QNU0OVBMB" style="font-size:12pt">
        m.FIRMA
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery [`.css()` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/) returns the **computed** style property.

Since you want to get the value that was specified in the inline style attribute, you could access the `fontSize` property on the element's [`style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) directly in order to get `12pt`.

```js
var element = document.getElementById('_QNU0OVBMB'),
    fontSize = element.style.fontSize;

alert(fontSize); // 12pt
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="_QNU0OVBMB" style="font-size:12pt">
  m.FIRMA
</div>
```

Likewise, with jQuery you would just need to access the DOM element in the jQuery object:

```js
var fontSize = $('#_QNU0OVBMB')[0].style.fontSize;

alert(fontSize); // 12pt
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="_QNU0OVBMB" style="font-size:12pt">
  m.FIRMA
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The alert is showing you size in PIXELS, and 16px does = 12pts

[Pixel to point converter](http://endmemo.com/sconvert/pixelpoint.php)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't say 16pt it says 16px, which is how chrome is rendering that directive. Points are generally only for print media, if you use pixels it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try using !important when you want to override them. And 12pt = 16px.

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            var css = $('#_QNU0OVBMB').css(["font-size"]);
            alert(css["font-size"]);
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="_QNU0OVBMB" style="font-size:12px!important">
        m.FIRMA
    </div>
```